# Studying a series using the limit comparison test

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, solution-verification

I wanted to determine when $\sum \frac{n}{n^{3x}+1}$ converges and when it is divergent by using the limit comparison test (please use the following method, which is the one used by my teacher, I know this exercise can be solved in an easier way but I'm interested in this very method). I evaluated $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}n^{3x} \cdot \frac{n}{n^{3x}+1}=l$ finding  $l > 0$  for $x \geq-1/3$. This means that my series behaves like $\sum \frac{1}{n^3x}$, so it will converge for $x >1/3$ and diverge for $-1/3 \leq x \leq1/3$. How do I find what happens to the series when $x<-1/3$ using this method?

Comment: If $x<-1/3$ then $\frac{n}{n^{3x}+1}>\frac{1}{2}n$

Comment: This doesn't use the limit comparison test in the way I specified